# Multiple optional parameters in Angular.js

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I typically use querystrings for filtering results, eg:

```
 URL:    /Events/List?type=art&city=miami&life=present
```

I can put them in any order and get the same results, eg:

```
 URL:    /Events/List?city=miami&life=present&type=art
 URL:    /Events/List?life=present&type=art&city=miami
```

I can also make them optional, eg:

```
 URL:    /Events/List?type=art, 
  or:    /Events/List?type=art&life=&city=
```

**Question: How can I achieve this same "effect" with Angular.js routes?** given the fact that parameters are passed all in a "RESTful" way in Angular

I was thinking in something like this:

```
 URL:   /Events/List/city/miami/life/present/type/art
```

Which I can achieve with a route like this:

```
 .when('/Events/List/city/:city?/life/:life?/type/:type?', { ... }
```

But I already see many problems:

1. Order of parameters is important (I would have to define many times the route?)
2. Optional parameters will give a non intuitive URL, 
   eg: `/Events/List/city/life/type/art`, 
   and this is not the case in optional querystrings (they are more intuitive to read I think):
    eg: `/Events/List/?city=&life=&type=art`

Comment: Do you want a different route depending on the parameters?

Comment: mm no, I want one controller for all of those routes, just like in ASP.NET MVC I have one action that receives all those GET parameters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use query strings angular has `$location.search()` that is both a setter and getter.

The difference between angular `search`  and window version `location.search` is the query falls after the url hash and when setting or getting it uses objects rather than strings

See [**Using $location**](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location) in developer's guide

Comment: Marked as accepted because it clarifies that I can still use query strings combined with angular's URL's, that is: `#/bla/bla?bla=bla`

Answer (score 1):

You can inject $routeParams into your controller. Here's an example from the docs:

```
// Given:
// URL: http://server.com/index.html#/Chapter/1/Section/2?search=moby
// Route: /Chapter/:chapterId/Section/:sectionId
//
// Then
$routeParams ==> {chapterId:1, sectionId:2, search:'moby'}
```

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute.$routeParams

Answer (score 1):

I recently encountered a similar need (the ability to grab an unknown quantity of arguments off the path), and had started off by looking at $routeProvider.  I ultimately abandoned that effort in favor of [ui.router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing).

The most powerful (but possibly also tedious) approach for you would be to work with [regex parameters](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#regex-parameters).  Consider the following (a snippet from some code I'm currently authoring):

```
$stateProvider
    .state("list", {
        url: "/",
        controller: "PluginsListController",
        templateUrl: "PluginsList.html"
    })
    .state("path", {
        url: "/{plugin}/*path",
        controller: "PluginDetailsController",
        templateUrl: "PluginDetails.html"
    })
;
```

The second state accepts two positional parameters:  a `plugin` and a `path`.  The `path` argument is a wildcard, that grabs everything after the immediately preceding slash.  The idea here is that I can specify something like http://www.myfirsturl.com/app/MyFirstPlugin/level1/level2/level2.php, and end up with "MyFirstPlugin" in `$stateParams["plugin"]` and "level1/level2/level2.php" in `$stateParams["path"]`.  It's up to the application logic to handle the long path parameter (and you would be likewise responsible for consuming this variable-length argument), but this approach does allow you to write a single state handler for an unknown number of url paths.